# How to retain tiling information(contentTransform property) of a texture in SceneKit while saving/exporting the scene to .dae format?

Tags: swift, macos, scenekit

I am facing an issue while exporting a scene to .dae format in mac. I have created a Scene with Front, Left and Right walls along with a Floor and three 3D .dae models. For walls, I have set a texture like this.

```
wall.geometry!.firstMaterial!.diffuse.contents = "art.scnassets/wall.jpg"
wall.geometry!.firstMaterial!.diffuse.contentsTransform = SCNMatrix4Mult(SCNMatrix4MakeScale(8, 2, 1), SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation(0, 1, 0));
wall.geometry!.firstMaterial!.diffuse.wrapS = SCNWrapMode.Repeat;
wall.geometry!.firstMaterial!.diffuse.wrapT = SCNWrapMode.Mirror;
```

This is how it looks when I run the application.
[image]

Now, I would like to export this to **.dae** format so that Blender or 3DS max can directly take this as an input and render high quality image out of it. This is the code which I have written to export the scene to .dae format.

```
scnView.scene!.writeToURL(NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/srikanth/Mac/TestRender/TestRender/testrender.dae"), options: nil, delegate: nil, progressHandler: nil)
```

The exported file looks something like this. 
[image]

This is the image which I am using as a texture for walls and it is repeated horizontally and vertically by the contentTransform property of wall material.

[image]

**.dae** exported file has all the information except the **contentsTransform** property applied to the material. I would like to retain this information also when I export. Contradictory thing is, If I export the same scene to **.scn** format, **contentsTransform** property value is retained, but the only problem is that I did not find any tool or software which reads **.scn** other than Xcode.

Please help me out on how to retain contentTransform property of a material while exporting to **.dae** format or any plugin or software which helps me to read .scn file.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it, but I wonder if you'd fare better using Model I/O to export. Per [WWDC 2015 Model I/O talk](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-602/), you can write STL and OBJ, but apparently not DAE.

```
import SceneKit.ModelIO

let asset = MDLAsset(SCNScene: scene!)
asset.exportAssetToURL
```